# Calculate the rate of decomposition of H2O2 at 25 °C when [H2O2] is exactly 10.0 mmol/L

Tags: kinetics, concentration

I'm really confused?

$$\ce{2H2O2 -> 2H2O + O2}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccc}\hline
\text{Experiment no.} & c(\ce{H2O2}) & \text{rate} \\
\hline
1 & 14.45 & 3.35 \times 10^{-3}\\
2 & 28.90 & 6.65 \times 10^{-3}\\
3 & 57.80 & 13.35 \times 10^{-3}\\
\hline\end{array}$$

So from previous parts of the question, I found the order of reaction (1<sup>st</sup>), the rate equation for the reaction ($r = k[\ce{A}]$), the rate constant ($2.3 \times 10^{-4}\ \mathrm{s}^{-1}$, which is correct according to the answers), and now I need to find the rate of decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$ when $\ce{[H2O2]}$ is exactly $10.0\ \mathrm{mmol\ L^{-1}}$.

I thought it's just $2.3 \times 10^{-4} \times 10.0$, which is $2.3 \times 10^{-3}$, but the answers provided is double that (so $4.6 \times 10 ^{-3}$), so I must have gotten the rate equation wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It is a matter of definition:

The rate of the reaction is defined as: $$r=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d[\ce{H2O2}]}{dt}$$
The rate of the decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$ is defined as:$$r_{\mathrm{decomp}}=-\frac{d[\ce{H2O2}]}{dt}= 2r$$

Comment: so if I'm calculating for k, would I use r = k[H2O2]?

Comment: Yes. Your calculation of k is quite right.

Comment: so if, for example, the rate was r = (-2)*(d[H2O2]/dt), would rate of decomposition be (1/2)*r? am I understanding this relationship correctly?

Comment: In the expression of the reaction rate on devise by the stoichiometric coefficients of each reactant or product.

Comment: The rate of decomposition of a reactant or the rate of formation of a product is given without dividing by the stoichiometric coefficients .

Answer (score -2):

The correct answer depends on what who wrote the problem had in mind about the values of rates  in the  last column in the data table:

If he considers the  rate is  rate of decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$      , then  the answer is $2.3\times 10^{−3}$

If he considers the  rate is  rate of formation of $\ce{O2}$, then  the answer is $4.6\times10^{−3}$,

How we answer if we write the balanced equation in this way:

> $\ce{H2O2 -> H2O + 1/2 O2}$